# How Can I Add SEO To my Website?

Tags: search, seo, google-search

I would like to know how we can add a proper search result (see the linked picture) on Google search results. Is there a minimum visitor count required or something similar required?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean the search box?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2431095/how-do-i-get-a-search-box-to-appear-in-my-site-s-search-results), you need this mark up on your site:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
          “@context”: “http://schema.org”   
          “@type”: “WebSite”  
          “url”: “https://www.example.com/”,   
          “potentialAction”: {   
                 “@type”: “SearchAction”,
                 “target”: “https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}”,
                 “query-input”: “required name=search_term_string”
           }
    }
</script>
```

With **url** and **target** whatever they need to be for your site.